# Capture TCP traffic from a known process when it starts

Tags: linux, sniffing

I need to capture the TCP communications that a process makes. However, I cannot just run the process, go look up its PID, and then capture. I need to get the communications that occur an instant after it starts.

It is evidently making a JSON request, over an unknown port (not 80), to another process, that registers its URL for REST calls. I have to mimick its before and thus, I need to see it.

Is there a way to capture network communications over a particular interface without knowing the port and from the time the process starts onward?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww You don't ever sniff your http traffic while developing network communications? It's so much a part of my job description, it's on page one of my resume...for Windows development. imo, its just one drawer lower in the toolbox than the debugger is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tcpdump command in order to capture the traffic from/to your machine.
The size of the packets, port, interface, protocol and lots of parameters are covered by that.
for example: sudo tcpdump -i eth0 src/dst xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port x

for more detail, please check the tcpdump manual page. 
Note, be careful about printing the output to the file, because the result of the packet capturing command will be huge.

BR,

Comment: Yea, I've been using tcpdump and putting the results into wireshark for viewing. However, I cannot figure out how to filter with tcpdump to only capture http traffic, especially without knowing what port the process is using.

Comment: For example you run this command: sudo tcpdump -i any tcp -w /tmp/test.tcap Well, you have to set a Filter to see what you want. If you are using a new version of Wireshark to check the result, in the top of the app, there is an empty space to create a filter. You will write "http" there,then all the http packets will be shown. Note: As long as your filter is not correct, the background of box will be red. When your filter is correct, it will be shown as green.